# Is there a way to determine which columns are the result of a SQL aggregate function in JDBC?

Tags: jdbc, google-apps-script

Say I have a SQL statement of:

`SELECT airport, COUNT(1) as ct FROM airports GROUP BY 1`

Is there a way to determine from JDBC `getMetaData` which columns are in the `GROUP BY`

```
query = 'SELECT airport, COUNT(1) as ct FROM airports GROUP BY 1'
var rs = stmt.executeQuery(query);
var curRow = rs.getMetaData();
```

Answer (score 0):

I figured this out shortly after posting, this may not always work, but it works fine for my use case. I used the table name of the column and tested if it was > 0.

```
query = 'SELECT airport, COUNT(1) as ct FROM airports GROUP BY 1'
var rs = stmt.executeQuery(query);
var curRow = rs.getMetaData();
console.log('getColumnName', curRow.getColumnName(2))
console.log('getColumnLabel', curRow.getColumnLabel(2))
var tabName = curRow.getTableName(2)
console.log('tabName.length', tabName.length)
if (tabName.length > 0) {
  console.log('tabName is legit', tabName)
} else {
  console.log('tabName is not legit', tabName)
}
```